# apt-get update cannot connect to server

Tags: networking, server, apt, updates

I try to get update on my Ubuntu 15.04 but if failed to connect to server

```
me@me:~$ sudo apt-get update 
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

I tried to find solutions but cannot fix it. Here what I tried so far:

1. Modify in `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.8.4
   ```
2. I tried to ping Ubuntu server

   ```
   me@me:~$ ping archive.ubuntu.com
   PING archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from likho.canonical.com (91.189.91.15): icmp_seq=1 ttl=41 time=259 ms
   64 bytes from likho.canonical.com (91.189.91.15): icmp_seq=2 ttl=41 time=257 ms
   64 bytes from likho.canonical.com (91.189.91.15): icmp_seq=3 ttl=41 time=255 ms
   64 bytes from likho.canonical.com (91.189.91.15): icmp_seq=4 ttl=41 time=288 ms
   ^C
   --- archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
   4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 255.160/265.270/288.347/13.437 ms
   ```
3. In Software & Update, change server to Main Server
4. In `/etc/apt/apt.conf` I found this line:

   ```
   Acquire::http::proxy 54.86.15.42:8080
   ```

   I tried to add `#` in front of it and didn't work. Then try to connect to 54.86.15.42:8080 and nothing happens.
   And ping to this address:

   ```
   me@me:~$ sudo ping 54.86.15.42
   PING 54.86.15.42 (54.86.15.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
   ^C
   --- 54.86.15.42 ping statistics ---
   16 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 14999ms
   ```

It seems related to proxy or firewall but I don't use any of them. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf`

Comment: The output of it was added, I'm new to this forum so I'm not format code well to make it easy.

Comment: Try this `echo | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @A.B. Thank you, that worked for me. I am a Linux novice, and an expert customer tinkered with this computer, so I could no longer download anything from any repo. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was solved. I don't know what makes it works again. I tried these command `unset http_proxy` and `unset https_proxy` as @nilesh_101 suggested. One more thing I did is change proxy and then change it to default again. Thanks all you guys for answering my question!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.Then i clear all the contents of apt.conf file and it works perfectly.

Comment: The content was cleared, but it don't work.

Comment: please post what is the output  for this command                           "    env   |  grep  -i  proxy "

Comment: Try this                                                                                                                                 1. unset http_proxy
2. unset https_proxy

Comment: The output of the `env | grep -i proxy
` is `http_proxy=http://54.86.15.42:8080/
`. What is that?

Comment: Did you try unset commands ? Which i hav posted above .

Comment: The unset command was not found pro

Comment: Your  output of env | grep -i proxy shows that still there is proxy.You can remove that by using 1.unset http_proxy 2. unset https_proxy

Comment: I used the command you said, but the output of `env | grep -i proxy` is still the same.

Comment: Check also in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc if you are not setting those variables at login.

Comment: Thanks you for your enthusiasm, my problem was solved. I'm so happy now =))

Comment: always welcome pro