# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS apt-get update error : Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: 14.04, apt, update-manager

I have a problem in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, when I run "apt-get update", an error message is shown : **E :Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.**

```
Ign http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty InRelease
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [3,396 B]
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Ign https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security InRelease
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [3,396 B]
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates Release.gpg
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty Release
Ign https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security Release.gpg
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [1,556 B]
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty Release
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/main amd64 Packages
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates Release
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports Release
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:5 https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ InRelease
Ign https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ InRelease
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security Release
Ign https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Packages
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Get:6 https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Translation-en_US
Hit http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Get:7 https://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease
Ign https://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/main Translation-en_US
Hit https://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Hit https://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release
Hit https://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit https://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Ign https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Translation-en_US
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Ign https://cran.rstudio.com trusty/ Translation-en
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign https://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://linux.dropbox.com trusty/main Translation-en
Err https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
  gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Err https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
  gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
Ign https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/main i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Err https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/main Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign https://ubuntu.mirror.tn trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Err https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  HttpError404
Err https://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  HttpError404
Fetched 23.8 kB in 25s (940 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Failed to connect to ubuntu.mirror.tn port 443: Connection refused

W: Failed to fetch https://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

W: Failed to fetch https://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  HttpError404

W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  HttpError404

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**note: I found many solutions in other forums: for example :**

**cd /var/lib/apt/lists/**

**/var/lib/apt/lists$ rm -vf ***

**apt-get update**

**apt-get upgrade**

**but those commands not resolve my problem**

Comment: Your errors all lok like failure to connect to various servers - are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Charles Green, Thank you for your response. No, I don't use any proxy

Comment: You might check [https://askubuntu.com/questions/204602/apt-get-install-not-working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204602/apt-get-install-not-working) and [https://askubuntu.com/questions/686130/apt-get-update-cannot-connect-to-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686130/apt-get-update-cannot-connect-to-server) - both reference accidently setting (and unsetting) a network proxy

Comment: I have tried all the solutions, but not  resolve my problem

Comment: Have you tried using a mirror other than the mirror in Tunasia?

Comment: yes, i tried many other mirror but the same error triggered

Comment: Can someone help me please !!!

Answer (score -1):

Tarroumi Mohamed - have you tried using a different internet connection, to isolate whether it is a router issue or not? You must clear everything as above first, to be sure it is the router.

Also try with a Live CD/DVD of the same OS version or newer (USB boot devices are handy but get infected more easily than one might think - see Stuxnet and BadUSB).

DNS corruption and other corruption of normal access (force-routing via an attacker's proxy) can obviously occur in routers, too. Especially as they are pretty much never very secure due to lazy / NSA-bribed manufacturers, etc.

Note: paranoia is a virtue in security, but only up to a point. Then it's unhealthy like everywhere else! None of your problems may be malicious, but the same procedures are used to troubleshoot, in effect.